# C++ inheritence calling base class member function using derived class

Tags: c++

May be my question is wrong. I am new to C++.
Is there any way call a base class member function using derived class object if that function is being overridden in derived class?

For example:

```
class A {
public:
    void add() { cout<<"A"; }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void add() { cout<<"B"; } 
};

int main() {
    B bObj; 
    bObj.add(); // calls member function of class B
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you aren't really overriding the `add` function, merely hiding the name, since `A::add` is not declared `virtual`.

To call `A::add`, just be explicit about it:

```
bObj.A::add();
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, `B::add()` exists for a reason and you probably shouldn't be calling `A::add()` on a `B`. Which isn't to say you can't - you just have to turn it into an `A` first:

```
B bObj;
static_cast<A&>(b).add(); // calls A::add()
```

Or explicitly specify that it's `A::add()`:

```
bObj.A::add();
```

From *within* `B`, you have to qualify the call:

```
class B: public A {
public:
    void add() { cout<<"B"; } 

    void test() {
        add();    // calls B::add
        A::add(); // calls A::add
    }
};
```